# Authentcated user login from JSON response -React Native

Tags: react-native

I am building a small application in react native containing login and signup module. For authenticated user login I am trying to fetch data using JSON. I am using PHP as backend. My code in react native is as follows for login.

**Login.js**

```
fetch('http://localhost/app/signup.php' ,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept' : 'application/json' ,
            //'Content-Type': 'application/json' 
        },
        body : JSON.stringify({
            contact : this.state.contact,
            password: this.state.password
        })
    }).then(() => 
    {       
        response => response.json();
        if(response.json == true)
        {
         const routeStack = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
         this.props.navigator.jumpTo(routeStack[1]);
        }
        else
        {
        const routeStack = this.props.navigator.getCurrentRoutes();
         this.props.navigator.jumpTo(routeStack[0]);
        }
    });
```

what changes do i need to make?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch json data from server then you should use axios library.if you want to install this library simply run command

```
   npm install --save axios
```

in command prompt in your project folder.

Example of axios code in react - native:-

```
 state = { abc:[] };

 componentWillMount() {

 axios.get('url')//lowercase a
 .then(response => this.setState({abc:response.data})).catch((error) => {
 console.error(error);
 });
 }
```

abc contain your fetched data.Then use map for further use of this data.
Further detail on axios read documentation 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios

Comment: okay so how do i decode the json response returned from server?

Comment: when you store json data in abc in above example then use map for storing it. like this:-                                                                                                        return  this.state.albums.map(albumon =>
    <AlbumDetail key = {albumon.title} album = {albumon} />                                                                               //here albumon is array which contain all the value of your json with there respective object.

Comment: sorry i am confused with axios method , i tried using fetch method its working when i am sending JSON. Now i am trying to decode the response returned. Is stringify.json will work?